# Refreshing view in relativeLayout

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout

Here is my layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="1280dp"
    android:layout_height="800dp">


    <al.android.emcr.MainDisplay
        android:layout_width="1280dp"
        android:layout_height="800dp"/>
    <al.android.emcr.menu.MenuDisplay
        android:layout_width="1280dp"
        android:layout_height="114dp"/>

    <al.android.emcr.popups.ConfigurePopup.ConfigurePopup
        android:layout_width="1280dp"
        android:layout_height="800dp" />

</RelativeLayout>`
```

When I refresh my "MainDisplay" view with `invalidate`(), there's no problem.
But when I try to do it with my MenuDisplay with the same method, the view is not refreshed.
What am I doing wrong ?

**Note:** the both views have the "onDraw(Canvas)" method implemented.

**Note2:** I call the invalidate() method in the main thread.
I'm wondering if the fact one of the views overlay the other has any wrong effect on the views refresh.

**Note3:** The `onTouch`() event work fine on both views.

Comment: what do u mean by refresh? what are you doing that needs refreshing?

Comment: Once I've changed my content view, I want to display the new view !

Comment: kindly show some more code . currently the xml doesn't even have id for the views ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solve my issue :
in the MenuDisplay class I had two constructors :

`public MenuDisplay(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
super (c,attrs);
        init(c);
    }`

and `public MenuDisplay(Context c) {
        super(c);
        init(c);
    }`

What it caused my problem it was that I called init(c) in both methods.
I think, the best solution consists in call the init method in the native View method : onFinishInflate() with eventually a static counter to call init only for the last inflate occurence (if they are many inflates for the same view) !